# The list of Numpy arrays that are passed to model is not the size the model expected

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, keras, visualization

I am trying to visualize the layers of convolutional and capsule networks. The code for visualization is as follows:

```
layer_outputs = [layer.get_output_at(0) for layer in model.layers[:12]# Extracts the outputs of the top 12 layers
activation_model = models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=output_layer) # Creates a model that will return these outputs, given the model input
activations = activation_model.predict(img_tensor)
```

here, img_tensor is array of shape (1,28,28,1). An image from mnist dataset. The execution of code throws error as follows:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[0.0000000e+00],
     [0.0000000e+00],
     [0.0000000e+00],
     [0.0000000e+00],
     [0.0000000e+00],
     [0.0000000e+00],
     [0.0000000e+00],
     [0.00000...
```

The error occurs due to line `activations = activation_model.predict(img_tensor)`.

Can anyone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your input dimensionality does not match the model definition.

Quick debug: Compare your input shape with the input layer shape from the model summary.

Comment: The input layer shape is (none,28,28,1). By input shape, u mean the shape of img_tensor?

Comment: yes, The model summary gives you expected input and output shapes and how they evolve at each layer. You can check that for reference. Make sure that the image_tensor shape matches the input layer expected dimensions.